# How do i show a country map and make cities separate by changing color of mouseover

Tags: asp.net

How do i show a country map and make cities separate by changing color of mouseover

I need an Idea how to do it like [www.mudah.my](http://www.mudah.my/) site.

Answer (score 1):

Basically how they (http://www.mudah.my/) do is by having 1 normal map image with no country highlighted (actually it looks like they use a couple images but make it like 1 image by placing a transparent div over the top of them).

They have a standard image map applied to this '1' image to define the separate areas and when the user mouses over a relevant part of the map they display a specify section of the highlight image (http://www.mudah.my/img/map_highlight.png) in a specific place on top the the existing image, but behind the 1 main transparent div.  Presumably so the links associated with the image map) continues to work.

Hope this helps.